# Why are the high bits set to 1 in so much of what I see when inspecting random addresses in lldb?

Tags: x86, reverse-engineering, lldb

I don't know how to use this tool very well, I was only ever a mediocre C programmer, and my knowledge of assembly stops right about at the 6502.

This is on a Mac, retail software, and it's a 32-bit Intel executable. If I perform the following command:

```
(lldb) expr ((char *) 0xa5baddf2)
```

I will often see strings that resemble (to my ignorant eyes):

```
(char *) $63 = 0xa5baddf2 "\xffffff83\xffffffc4\x10\xffffff89\xffffffc6\xffffff8b\xffffff87\xffffffe6A\x0e\x04\xffffff85\xffffffc0t\x12\xffffff83\xffffffec\fj\x01\xffffffffu\x10\xffffffffu\fSV\xffffffff\xffffffd0\xffffff83\xffffffc4 \xffffff81\xfffffffb\x01\b"
```

This is in hex of course because they aren't ascii printable, and it likely terminates just where there's some random null byte. Why are the top 24 (or so) bits always 0xffffff? Given that the low bits (the actual value) appear normal, these are probably unsigned ints or something like that, and it being a 32-bit executable it would pad those out I should think. But if so, shouldn't the high bits all be zeroed?

This doesn't much make sense to me whether they'd be unsigned or signed (I don't think two's complement would look like this).

Comment: It could just be small negative integers (2's complement).  e.g. `-1` is `0xffffffff`, `-100` is `0xffffff9c` as an `int32_t`.  Or packed structs?  The `\x10` seems odd, like it's a single byte between 32-bit integers, so not all the integers can be aligned.  Of course a small positive `int32_t` would contain a `\x00` byte and terminate the C string after the low byte.

Comment: They're probably not addresses; if MacOS is like Linux, the top page of virtual address space is reserved.  But if not, they *could* be stack addresses.  (Under a 64-bit kernel, 32-bit user space owns the whole 4GiB).  Hard to guess further without having any clue what the software might possibly be doing with data at the address you dumped; that's often a big clue.  Or what kind of software it is.  e.g. if it's working with a packed bitstream or compression format?

Comment: @PeterCordes I see values like this way too often to think they're all negative ints. I'll just check random breakpoints, and pull addresses off the stack, which I think on this arch are supposed to be the arguments passed into the functions. 1 in 10 will be human readable strings, the rest are like this. I had assumed it was just something obvious to non-morons (that doesn't include me), something low-level about the architecture, or maybe about lldb itself.

Comment: Like consistently 3 bytes of leading ones?  I'd expect pointers to be very common, and it's very plausible for many of them to have 2 bytes of leading ones, but more surprising for them to all be in the top 256 bytes.  At least if it's a C program; IDK what language your program was compiled from.

Comment: @PeterCordes This seems to be an ObjC executable, but I've set breakpoints in dylibs that are definitely just vanilla C and seeing much the same thing even in those places. I guess I need to debug some command line binary, see if it looks the same as this...